# Scrollspy in a Modal seems confused in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem when Scrollspy is inside the Modal. The problem is when I hover the scrollbar, it seems the navigation bar don't what nav id to be hover.

I put the scrollablle are here:

```
<div class="modal-body" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-how-to" style="height:200px; overflow:auto;">
<!-- some div -->
</div>
```

I put it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLHxY/) to see it on action. Just click on How To (Read Instruction) to show the modal.